# how do I prove all group properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, function-and-relation-composition

$G(x) = ax + b$ where $a$ is not equal to $0$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Prove $G$ is a group under function composition.

I understand that for every $a$ there is a corresponding $b$-value that does not repeat; however, I do not understand how I can prove the group properties.

Answer (score 4):

First, $G(x) = ax +b$ is a function, not a set. Let $f_{a,b}$ be the function defined by $x \mapsto ax +b$. You want to show that

$$G = \{f_{a,b} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a \neq 0\}$$ is a group.

Normally, this would require you to check all group axioms, but because you know that the set of bijective functions (i.e. the functions that have an inverse), together with function composition, is a group, it suffices to show that $G$ is a subgroup of this group, for which you have to show $3$ things:

1) $G \neq \emptyset$ (hint: consider the map: $x \mapsto x)$

2) $f_{a,b}, f_{c,d} \in G \implies f_{a,b} \circ f_{c,d} \in G$ (hint: what function is $f_{a,b} \circ f_{c,d}$?)

3) $f_{a,b} \in G \implies {f_{a,b}}^{-1} \in G$  (hint: what function is ${f_{a,b}}^{-1}$?)

Comment: You also need to prove associativity, which will depend on the fact that addition and multiplication in the reals are associative.  It is similar to 2)-just write out the expression and it falls out.

Comment: You don't need to show this. This follows because $G$ is a subset of the group of bijections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're more familiar with matrices, then the group is isomorphic to the set of $2\times 2$ matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{ a & b \\ 0 & 1}
$$
It is easy to see that function composition corresponds to matrix multiplication.

Comment: I don't know how you obtained this matrix but I found a different one. The set of linear functions $G$ is a $2$ dimensional vector space. A basis for this vector space is formed by $1$ (a linear function) and $x$ (a linear function). To map each $G$ as a matrix one has to find the first column as the coefficients of the image of $G$ on $1$ wich gives $0.x+(a.1+b).1 $ and for the second column the image of $G$ on $x$ : $a.x + b.1$ giving the matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a+b & a \\ 0 & b\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts, I found that matrix by considering the action on vectors of the form $(x,1)$, a standard technique for representing translations as matrices.

Comment: I don't get why translations are involved in the composition of linear functions.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations for instance.  BTW, $ax+b$ is an *affine* function.

Comment: I realize i messed up the calculations. In the vector space of first degree polynomials $1$ and $x$ form a basis and the composition gives $1 \mapsto 1$ and $x \mapsto ax+b$ giving exactly the same matrix as you have.